# Numpy sum of minimums of two arrays like dot product efficiently

Tags: python, numpy

I would like get two arrays' sum of minumums efficiently with numpy. For example;

```py
X=np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,0]])
Y=np.array([[0,2,0],[1,3,1]])
```

My result should be;

```py
result = array([[2, 4],[2, 3]])
```

The calculation for first cell;

```py
result[0,0] = min(X[0,0],Y[0,0])+ min(X[0,1],Y[0,1])+min(X[0,2],Y[0,2])
```

In general, the result should be:

```
res[i,j] = sum(np.minimum(X[i, :], Y[j, :]))
```

but looking for fastest way.

Comment: My interpretation: combine all vectors mutually to each other: `result[i,j] = sum(min(X[i, :], Y[j, :]))`.

Comment: The optimal way depends on your memory limitations, the size of your vectors, the length of the lists, the actual data structures you need/have (e.g. is it really a 2d np array in the first place, and do we need an np array in the end). Any hints for us?

Comment: Arrays shapes are like (1000, 40000). No limitation memory for now , I am looking for fastest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dot` is the equivalent of taking outer products, and summing on the appropriate axis.

The equivalent in your case is:

```
In [291]: np.minimum(X[:,None,:], Y[None,:,:])
Out[291]: 
array([[[0, 2, 0],
        [1, 2, 1]],

       [[0, 2, 0],
        [1, 2, 0]]])
In [292]: np.sum(np.minimum(X[:,None,:], Y[None,:,:]),axis=-1)
Out[292]: 
array([[2, 4],
       [2, 3]])
```

Comment: I was not aware of `np.minimum` being able to broadcast. Beautiful! :)

Comment: Though I fear you run into memory trouble for the given vectors of length `40000` without any divide strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Best I could do:

```py
import numpy as np


def sum_mins(x, y):
    mask = (X - Y) < 0
    return np.sum(X*mask + Y*np.logical_not(mask))


X=np.array([1,2,3])
Y=np.array([0,2,0])

print(sum_mins(X, Y))
```

Answer (score 0):

One naive approach close to definition:

```
result = np.array([[np.sum(np.minimum(v_x, v_y)) for v_y in Y] for v_x in X])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I need more efficient way because my data is very big. This way is taking too much time.

Comment: Yes, I guess so. This is just the straight forward way to do it. It may serve as reference for all the great solutions to come :)

Comment: I tested this way. These results are twice as slow as dot product, but seems acceptable.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you implement the solution based on a dot product?

Comment: I am trying to get similarity matrix for theese arrays. I want to use weighted jaccard similarity (http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en/us/pubs/archive/36928.pdf).
sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances (for cosine) makes in 2 seconds. dot product is 33 seconds. your solution is 67 secs.

Comment: Just to get you right with the comparison: dot product is not a solution to your problem, but you compare against it because it is so similar?

Comment: Yes. It is like same math problem. Instead of sum of products, it should be sum of minimums. Also, sklarn is making too fast and I am trying to understand how it is that fast.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of hpaulj's and my former answer (deleted) that works in case you run out of memory otherwise:

```
# maximum number of float32s in memory - determining a max. chunk size
MAX_CHUNK_MEM_SIZE = 1000 * 1024 * 1024 / 4


def _fast_small(x, y):
    """Process a case with small size of x and y."""
    # see answer of @hpaulj
    return np.sum(np.minimum(x[:, None, :], y[None, :, :]), axis = -1)


def fast(x, y):
    """Process a case with potentially large size of x and y."""
    assert len(x.shape) == len(y.shape) == 2
    assert x.shape[1] == y.shape[1]
    num_chunks = int(np.ceil(x.shape[0] * y.shape[0] * x.shape[0] / MAX_CHUNK_MEM_SIZE))
    result_blocks = []
    for x_block in np.array_split(x, num_chunks):
        result_blocks_row = []
        for y_block in np.array_split(y, num_chunks):
            result_blocks_row.append(_fast_small(x_block, y_block))
        result_blocks.append(result_blocks_row)
    return np.block(result_blocks)
```